# autolayout- different devices and rotation

Tags: ios, swift

I am absolutely new in iOS programming. I wonder if  a View contains 4 narrow rectangle subviews where they are constraints to four sides, like a picture frame, if I can make this program works in portrait, landscape; in all devices, iPad, iPhone( different version). The reason I am asking is to find out if not possible to consider concentrating and finding out about the possible options.
thanks

Comment: Short answer? Yes, auto layout is the correct way. Longer answer (and apologies if harsh sounding) this site isn't meant for such a question. It's about to be flagged because you have no code, no specific issues, and obviously don't know what MCVE (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) stands for. The questions here are meant to be a bit more higher level than this - and the least you could have searched for (hint) is something like "adaptive layout", "size classes", or maybe even "auto layout constraints" along with "iOS".

Comment: Not sure what to say...Thank you! very informative

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes, auto layout will do it. you might want to take a look at this tutorial to get started:

https://www.raywenderlich.com/115440/auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-9-part-1-getting-started-2

Comment: Thank you for this. I looked into the same link yesterday and I also found another link, youtube one as follows  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RH_Ye-8ii8E